# Haskell return the first two letters of a string that is followed by a number

Tags: haskell

How could I go about writing a function that takes a string:
**4vkYyAO174midQTt0**

and returns the first two letters that are followed by a number. So for example in this case it should return:

**AO**

How would I write a function like this?

So far I have tried:

```
cipher :: String -> String
cipher "" = ""
cipher [x] = ""
cipher (x:z:y:xs)
    |isDigit y && isLetter z && isLetter x = [x,z]
    |otherwise = cipher (y:xs)
```

However when done this way the function returns `Tt` instead of `AO`.

Which part am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made any progress? e.g. return the first letter followed by a number, or even just the first letter.

Comment: Step 1 to solving this is thinking about how you, as a human would solve it. Think about that, try to implement it and then come back if you did not manage. Most people here are willing to help, just not willing to solve the entire problem for you.

Comment: Consider that a string is a list of characters. You can pattern match the first three characters and the tail of a list: `(c1:c2:c3:tail)`. If `c3` is a digit and `c1` and `c2` are _not_ then surely `c1` and `c2` are the two characters you're looking for. If not, how do you check the rest of the string?

Comment: `cipher(x:z:y:xs)` recurses as `cipher (y:xs)`, i.e. it throws away two letters. So on your example you first remove 4v then kY then yA then O1 ... oops!

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion throws away two letters at the beginning of the string each time. It also fails to account for a list with two elements.

If we try `cipher "teh3"` it would consider `"teh"` first, then recursive call `cipher "h3"` which would result in a match failure.

Give than there may not be a match, it makes more sense to return `Maybe String`. It would also make sense to list the three (or more) character string pattern first, and then have a catch-all pattern return `Nothing`.

```
cipher :: String -> Maybe String
cipher (x:tl@(y:z:xs))
  | isDigit z && all isLetter [x,y] = Just [x,y]
  | otherwise = cipher tl
cipher _ = Nothing
```